# Clustered key for column used in ON (Join) clause vs WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table (tblContracts) with millions of rows. Presently the ContractID column is a clustered (index) primary key. There are various reports that run on this table that also joins to couple of more tables (on ContractID column); most of the reports have WHERE clause referring to a date column (tblContracts.StartDate)

I am planning to change the table design by making the ContractID column as non-clustered index and the tblContracts.StartDate column as clustered. Idea being that most of the selected columns are from the tblContracts table and if the data is ordered on disk based on StartDate column then the WHERE clause (and the select statement on this table) will run more faster. My concern is that - will doing this adversely impact the joins (that are on ContractID column)?

Comment: Probably better to ask on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Test it in a dev environment.

Comment: Absolutely no way we can answer this for you as we don't have access to your environment.  As @MJH suggests, run a test and find out which performs better

Comment: Actually, the joins will probably speed up, because the non-clustered index is smaller. The kicker is, of course, that looking up anything besides the ID and the date (which is presumably why the join is happening in the first place) will slow down because an extra clustered index lookup is required, and that can have a grave impact. To combat this, you can include columns in the index, but if you go overboard with this inserts and updates will slow down. TL;DR: you can't really know if one improvement will beat out the other without measuring things.

Comment: Justify your change. Absent any real reasons, there is nothing to suggest you change what appears to be an existing and well-performing production system.